# How Edward managed to escape from Gluttony?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

In Episode 24 and 25 of Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood, Ed, Ling Yao and Envy are trapped in a sub-dimension that was created for storing everything that Gluttony has ever swallowed.

Envy told that there's no escape, but Ed has found out something. What did he do exactly?

As far as I can get, he did human transmutation to open the Gate of Truth and by this, he can escape. But how is it possible? Since the sub-dimension is separated from the actual world.

Also, why Ed didn't lose anything when he opened the Gate again? Why Envy and Ling neither?

Comment: which anime are you in? the new or the old?

Comment: "In Episode 24 and 25 of *Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood*"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gluttony was created to be a second Gate of Truth but is only a failed copy. Ed had the idea that because they came there through the failed gate, they must be able to get back trough the real gate. It's just like creating a door back to Gluttony.

To open the Gate of Truth, he used Envys Philisopher's Stone and the old parts of the Xerxes mural to make this special human transmutation. The sacrifice for opening the gate was a soul of the Philisopher's Stone, which thanked him afterwards (because he freed the soul).

Comment: So it was not the same kind of human transmutation than the one that Elrics have done.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt It was close. The transmutation to create there mother was a transmutation of the "material" into another form, the transmutation inside Gluttony was the same, but without changing their form but only the position. I don't know, but I guess it's a similar principle.

Answer (score -1):

They didn't lose anything because Ed used the philosopher's stone. To create copies of themselves in the real world and transfer their souls to the copy of bodies he created.
So, he had to pass through the gate of truth for deleting his old self from gluttony.
Envy and Lin must also have passed through the original gate.
Ed could have brought back his limbs that moment.

Comment: What basis do you have for this idea of yours that they "create copies of themselves"?